# Discrepancy between tag stats - mobile app vs. web

Tags: support, bug

I was happily surprised, seeing that I was only 10 points from hitting 1k on Marketing Cloud tag, when looking at the SE mobile app:
[image]

However, the numbers on the web, are slightly lower:

[image]

I would assume, I should be seeing same figures across both platforms? Or is there a good reason for these being different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the figure in the mobile app includes question scores as well. The total score of [your questions in the [marketing-cloud] tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A36623+%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D+is%3Aq) is 17, which is also shown in the [tags tab of your profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36623/lukas-lunow?tab=tags) when you hover over it:

[image]

973 + 17 = 990 which is exactly the number shown in the app.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. But it’s no directly clear, that the stats in the app include questions.

Comment: No, it isn't. It won't be changed though; [the apps have been retired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/295232).